# Use IIS to consume SharePoint blog feed

Tags: iis, rss, blogs

If my SharePoint site's blog sits at: https://myDomain-public.sharepoint.com/blog but I want the public to see those posts when visiting http://www.myPublicSite.com/blog - an IIS8 (soon to be Azure)-based site.

What sorts infrastructure/code/configuration tasks do I have to perform? I've seen a handful of services but most seem to want to wrap my content. I'd like to treat the SP editor as a WYSIWYG tool and just pass thru whatever is formatted.

thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Big picture: Create an 'A' record in your custom domain and configure SP's public site to resolve to that domain.

Step by step and details http://365.webbrewers.com/Pages/webbrewerstest2.aspx. His site isn't supporting a direct link to the post in question - you'll need to search out the one titled '**Use separate sub domains (or domains) for BOTH your 365 public sites!**

Worth the trip if you want to accomplish something like this.